# Replace values in a column based on conditions (Max value) from multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

i have a dataset that i already filter like this

[image]

in this selection of this dataframe, i want to replace the value of `"max`" and `"critical"` column, because the "max" column is wrong, it should be showing the maximum value from pollutant value on that day ('pm10', 'so2', 'co', 'o3', 'no2') and the critical column should be showing the name of the maximum poluttant on that day

the desired result is :

```
tanggal stasiun                         pm10  so2   co  o3  no2 max   critical  categori
3515    2020-12-01  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)  22    17    4   19  8   22    PM10      BAIK
3516    2020-12-02  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)  25    18    4   28  7   28    o3        BAIK
3518    2020-12-04  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)  39    29    8   52  17  52    o3        SEDANG
3520    2020-12-06  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)  31    22    7   30  9   31    pm10      BAIK
3521    2020-12-07  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)  25    22    6   18  9   25    pm10      BAIK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first is necessary select column for processing - e.g. by first and last name in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2']
```

Or remove `max` and get numeric columns in [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df1 = df.drop(['max'], axis=1).select_dtypes(np.number)
```

But because there are non numeric columns first convert them to numeric:

```
#for integers
df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2'].astype(int)
#or for numeric if some bad values (strings)
df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

And then assign `max` and [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['max'] = df1.max(axis=1)
df['critical'] = df1.idxmax(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
         tanggal             stasiun  pm10  so2  co  o3  no2  max critical  \
3515  2020-12-01  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)    22   17   4  19    8   22     pm10   
3516  2020-12-02  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)    25   18   4  28    7   28       o3   
3518  2020-12-04  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)    39   29   8  52   17   52       o3   
3520  2020-12-06  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)    31   22   7  30    9   31     pm10   
3521  2020-12-07  DKI1 (Bunderan HI)    25   22   6  18    9   25     pm10   

     categori  
3515     BAIK  
3516     BAIK  
3518   SEDANG  
3520     BAIK  
3521     BAIK
```

Comment: it gives an error `attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence`

Comment: @DiazJubairy - Can you change `df['critical'] = df1.idxmax(axis=1)` to `df['critical'] = df1.dropna(how='all').idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: @DiazJubairy - Because seems there is some row with only NaNs, so failed solution for this row.

Comment: still gives an error `ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence`

Comment: If use `df1 = df.drop(['max'], axis=1).select_dtypes(np.number)` get same output like `df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2']` ?

Comment: no, the one with `df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2']` the result is dataframe of poluttant type, but the one with `df1 = df.drop(['max'], axis=1).select_dtypes(np.number)` gives only the index

Comment: @DiazJubairy - because there are values not numeric. Need `df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` for `df1` instead solutions from question. Can you test it?

Comment: when use `df1 = df.loc[:, 'pm10':'no2']` and then `df['max'] = df1.max(axis=1)
df['critical'] = df1.dropna(how='all').idxmax(axis=1)` it still gives an error `TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`

Comment: maybe you should edit the answer so the other will be helped too, thank you

Comment: @DiazJubairy - sure, added to answer.